# C# split received string based on a separator and save into multiple variables

Tags: c#

I have a simple socket server which is receiving a string from client, now i am trying to split the received string and save it into multiple variables.

**this is an example string (will be different depending of different clients):**

```
Value0_Value1_Value2_Value3_Value4_END5
```

**this is the section of the code for splitting the string :**

```cs
if (content.IndexOf("END5") > -1)
{
    // All the data has been read from the
    // client. Display it on the console.  
    Console.WriteLine(content);

    //split the received string and save into Splitdata1 Arr[]
    string[] Splitdata1 = content.Split('_');

    //Save each split value into a separate variable
    string proce0 = Splitdata1[0];
    string proce1 = Splitdata1[1];
    string proce2 = Splitdata1[2];
    string proce3 = Splitdata1[3];
    string proce4 = Splitdata1[4];
    string proce5 = Splitdata1[5];

    //Print each value individually
    Console.WriteLine("individual strings: \n", "proce0", proce0,
                                                "\n", "proce1", proce1, 
                                                "\n", "proce2", proce2, 
                                                "\n", "proce3", proce3,
                                                "proce4", proce4, "\n",
                                                "proce5", proce5 );

    // Echo the data back to the client.  
    Send(handler, content);
}
```

**and this is the console output that i am getting when i send the string from client:**

> ```
> Waiting for a connection...
> Value0_Value1_Value2_Value3_Value4_END5
> individual strings:
>
> Sent 40 bytes to client.
> ```

I am not sure if its not splitting the string at all , or its just not printing the 6 string variables.
**What am i doing wrong ?**

Comment: _I am not sure if its not splitting the string at all , or its just not printing the 6 string variables_ Step through the code in the debugger and examine the values of the variables on each line.

Comment: I don't think Console.WriteLine works like that. Try concatenating all the variables into a single string before you write it to the console or use an [interpolated string](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated).

Comment: You are calling the wrong overload of [`Console.WriteLine`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.writeline?view=net-5.0#System_Console_WriteLine_System_String_System_Object___)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`Console.Writeline(String, Object[])`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.writeline#System_Console_WriteLine_System_String_System_Object___) expects you to provide a composite format string as your first argument, followed by the objects to write using that format string. In your case, you do not have any indexed placeholders in your first argument, so the subsequent arguments are ignored.

You can fix this by replacing your `Console.WriteLine` call with the below:

```
Console.WriteLine("individual strings:\n" +
    $"proce0: {proce0}\n" +
    $"proce1: {proce1}\n" +
    $"proce2: {proce2}\n" +
    $"proce3: {proce3}\n" +
    $"proce4: {proce4}");
```

Comment: @Charlieface: Cheers; I've clarified the overload now.

Answer (score 1):

`Console.WriteLine("individual strings: \n", "proce0", proce0,"\n", "proce1", proce1,"\n", "proce2", proce2, "\n", "proce3", proce3,"proce4", proce4, "\n","proce5", proce5 );`

This line doesn't concatenate the string together.
The first string need to contain where you want your other objects to be concatenate.
Like that:
`Console.WriteLine($"individual strings: \n proce0: {proce0} \n proce1: {proce1} \n proce2: {proce2} \n proce3: {proce3} \n proce4: {proce4} \n proce5: {proce5}");`

Answer (score 1):

[Console.WriteLine(string format, params object?[]? arg)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.writeline?view=net-5.0#System_Console_WriteLine_System_String_System_Object___) does doesn't accept arguments in that manner.

What you are doing is trying to insert the objects into a formattable string, the equivalent is using `string.Format`. Which will not work properly because you do not specify the index inside the string. It should look like -

```cs
// string.Format equivalent
Console.WriteLine("individual strings:\n" +
    "proce0: {0}\n" +
    "proce1: {1}\n" +
    "proce2: {2}", proce0, proce1, proce2);

// string interpolation
Console.WriteLine("individual strings:\n" +
    $"proce0: {proce0}\n" +
    $"proce1: {proce1}\n" +
    $"proce2: {proce2}");
```

There is also a way to do it without specifying each variable. So even if you send more data then expected it will display all data split on the '_' char regardless.

```cs
Console.WriteLine("individual strings:")
foreach(var data in Splitdata1)
{
    Console.WriteLine(data);
}
```